# SQL query to show file loading is stuck

Tags: sql-server, etl

Microsoft SQL Server is connected to our ETL (ab-initio) which shows the % progress of a file that is loading. When the file is running successfully the progress increases each time I run my file loading query but no other column updates including the date. Is there any way I can run a query which shows that a file is stuck running? This means that the progress would be stuck at the same number for 30 minutes or so. Please note that no date column updates as the progress increases for file loading.

```
Declare @Now DATETIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Declare @FromTimeStamp DATETIME= DATEADD (HOUR, -1, @NOW)

Select * from ExecuteFileStatus
Where Runstate = (‘RUNNING’)
And Progress = @FromTimeStamp
```

[This image shows File loading for one file after I run the following query-  select *
from ExecuteFileStatus
order by ABUpdateTime desc
I ran the query 3 separate times and as you can see the File has successfully run until it completely loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPjwZ.png)

Comment: HI @escsavar, you should include details of the table's structure, as well as some sample data and then your expected output (based on the sample data, which might hopefully have some "in progress" loads, as well as some completed loads).  This will help people understand your requirements better.  (For example, you say there is a "Progress %" that is updated, but then you have an example query that seems to indicate "Progress" is a date/time column ...... so that's hard to know if you're even attempting to query the right thing without understanding the table structure and data)

Comment: If you change your query to `And Progress <= @FromTimeStamp` it'll show you all records where that date hasn't changed in the last hour (assuming it is updated with current date)

Comment: @Craig Thanks. I have attached the image that shows a File running and completely loading. As you can see the progress increased each time I ran my query until it hits 100% progress. If the file was stuck then the progress would remain the same number each time I ran the query. Sorry for confusing you with the date/time query but I was thinking that SQL Server would maybe be able to tell that the File was stuck if I ran it but it doesn't work so I guess not. Ideally I would connect this query to Tableau and I would get an alert once a File is stuck loading. (Progress # remains the same).

Answer (score 0):

So, in your particular case, it appears to be the "Started" column that indicates when the file upload started, so that's the column that you need to compare against the current time (with whatever offset you are going to use - eg. 30 minutes, 1 hour, etc.).

```
DECLARE @offset smallint; -- number of minutes to indicate upload delay
Declare @Now DATETIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

SELECT @offset = -60;
Declare @FromTimeStamp DATETIME = DATEADD (minute, @offset, @NOW);

Select * from ExecuteFileStatus
Where Runstate = (‘RUNNING’)
And [Started] <= @FromTimeStamp;
```

That's going to give you uploads that have been running for more than the offset amount of time.  If you really needed to check whether a particular upload is stuck at the same % for a set period of time, then you'd have to either a) go to the code that is doing the file upload, and include a date/time update whenever the progress is incremented (eg. could the "ABUpdate..." column have its value update when the progress changes?), or b) write off "snapshot" records of the file upload data to a separate table so that you can compare it as the progress changes - that's a reasonable task, though, and will depend on if you, yourself, have the necessary permissions to create tables, etc. in the database